# No rows in MSDB.dbo.sysmail_faileditems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, database-mail

Initially I was getting a "no SELECT privilege" error when attempting to query contents for a report I need to create.  So we granted `DatabaseMailUserRole` in MSDB to my account - I see columns, but none of the data we know to exist.

What am I missing that needs to be done for my account to see the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_id('sysmail_faileditems')) 
AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

Shows `sysmail_faileditems` definition is

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems WHERE sent_status = 'failed'
```

Looking at `sysmail_allitems`. The definition of that is

```
SELECT ...
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems
WHERE (send_request_user = SUSER_SNAME()) 
      OR (ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0) = 1)
```

So it looks like you need to be in the sysadmin role to see all results or the sending user to see filtered results.

Comment: I never tried the FOR XML to see the source, but it turns out the sysadmin thing was the issue though I can query `sysmail_mailitems` without issue.  W00t, problem solved-thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking at the wrong version of the table. Tables can be created under different user names. so database.dbo.mytable is different from database.klowrey.mytable.

Look for your table in Object Explorer. See if there are two tables with the same name under different users.